# how to open jqgrid add form when click on the custom button of jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

i've added custom button on the footer of jqgrid for adding record. The code is as under:

```
$("#jqgUsers").navGrid('#jqgpUsers', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false })
        .navButtonAdd('#jqgpUsers', {
            caption: "",            
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-plus",
        onClickButton: function () {
            alert("Adding Row");
        },
        position: "last"
    });
```

How can I open jqGrid add form while click on that add button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just call the [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) manually with "new" as the first parameter (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#adding_row) the documentation)

```
$(this).jqGrid("editGridRow", "new");
```

or with any [properties](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) or [events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) like for example

```
$(this).jqGrid("editGridRow", "new", {recreateForm: true, closeAfterAdd: true});
```

Comment: What if I want to change of the css for the add/edit form of jqgrid ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding an additional answer because I have a different scenario with a beforeShowForm event defined in my pager. In order to make sure the add row settings and events in my pager definition are used when the add row dialogue is opened with a custom button click I called

```
`$('#add_' + your_grid_name_here).click();`
```

Which will make sure your grid's pager settings are used. It's works the same as if the user pressed the '+' button in the pager.